# What Java "cross-platform" really mean?

Tags: java, android, linux, windows, cross-platform

Im confused what "cross-platform" really means. We can develop a Java application that can run on windows and on Linux or Mac too. But can we develop an app that will run on Android smartphone and on Windows PC too if both of them can have Java Virtual Machine installed?

Comment: You might have heard *Java is cross Platform*,  have you ever heard *Android is cross platform*?

Comment: and Windows is cross-platform? why can an app run on Windows and Mac, but not on Android?

Comment: Android != Java, Android has just java syntax, however code is compiled to byte code (java) and to dalvik bytecode (android).

Comment: and Windows == Java?

Comment: Android, Windows, and Mac are operating systems. Java is a programming language.

Comment: Yes, but i still dont understand why can an app run on Windows and Mac, but not on Windows and Android for example.

Comment: @Incredible You can develope a cross-platform app (that runs on Android, windows phone, iOS) but that has nothing to do with "Java beeing cross-platform"

Comment: @Incredible - For java, you have a *machine dependent JVM* which converts machine independent byte-code to machine dependent instructions and executes them. So, you have different JVMs for different *platforms*. Now, you can write an app for android and try executing it on  iOS / Windows OS. Yes, we are comparing apples and elephants here (Language and OS) but that will take some effort.

Comment: Just because an application is cross-platform does not mean it is available on all platforms.

Comment: But how can app run on Windows and Mac then?

Comment: @Incredible because of aliens

Comment: Because the person who wrote the application built compiled versions for Windows and Mac.

Comment: You wrong Incredible, app run in Mac but crawls in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write an application that runs on any machine that supports a JVM compatible with the one for which the program was written.  Besides a compatible JVM, the app is liable to depend on certain libraries; all those must be able to be run on the available JVM, and be available to the app.

For instance, I can write a 'desktop GUI' application, using the Swing package and a JVM anywhere from 1.4 and up.  Let's say I use language features that are dependent on Java version 1.6.  That application can run on any computer that has a JVM of 1.6 or greater and has the Swing libraries (and any other libraries I've used) available.

Android uses a specialized UI system, which makes sense given its environment.  I am unaware of any system outside of a development environment that allows you to run the Android UI stuff on other machines, but don't think it would be very hard to do.  But I also don't know that there's much market for it; few enough desktops have touchscreens, which the Android UI has to support at a pretty basic level.

Comment: Does it mean that when i import Swing libraries into Android device i will be able to run any application that uses Swing UI?

Comment: It means that IF YOU WERE ABLE to use Swing libraries on Android, that you could run Swing on Android.  Although I doubt that's possible, I have no direct information on it.  I expect that way, way deep in the Swing implementation is something that gets a canvas from the underlying OS on which Swing does its magic, and that there's not necessarily an equivalent construct in Android.  But hey, I hear they've ported Win95 onto a watch, so who knows?